# How to build a notification system for followed posts

Tags: node.js

MERN stack

In my app, you can follow users and when those users make a post, you should get a notification.

Currently, my `User` model has an array that lists all the users they're following as well as users who are following them:

```
users_you_follow: [ <object_ids>... ],
users_who_follow_you: [ <object_ids>... ]
```

My current idea looks something like this:

When a user makes a post in the frontend, we pass in the array of `users_who_follow_you` as well as the post details into the backend.

Then, using mongoose, parse the `users_who_follow_you` and find the users with the same ID's.

Finally, within that `User` model, I would store the post details along with some other metadata.

Then in the frontend, I would have a setInterval call to check if there are any new notifications.

This method although might work seems very server intense with all the API calls to check notifications. Is there a better way around this?

I currently don't know how to start on this process. From my research, some people said to use websockets while others say web workers.

What would be the best way to achieve something like this?

A very similar system to compare it to would be StackOverflows inbox thing. If a user comments on your post, the header/navbar shows a notification without having you to refresh your screen.

Thank you.

Comment: This is two problems really. First how do you find all "subscribed" users and get ready to notify them. Second is where and how this notification shows up in the front end? Websockets are for realtime chat like applications. Webworks or serviceworkers are what allows browsers to push native like notifications to a persons browser or phone. You should research a bit more and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: @GifCo I believe I can find all subcribed users pretty easily. Since the user model has the array of `users_who_follow_you`, I can just turn that array of objectIds into a string and pass that into my backend where I can then have a mongoose query to find all users with the same ID as the ones I passed in. On the frontend, itll just be a very basic bell icon that becomes a dropdown when clicked. Think facebook/reddit

Comment: Actually, stackoverflows notificaition/inbox system is something super similar to what I am trying to create. You get a small notification when someone comments on your question without having you to refresh the screen.

Comment: Also, from more research, websockets isnt just for chat applications. Apparently stackoverflow uses it for realtime post updates?

Comment: yes like I said websockets are for real time "chat like" applications. Anytime you need a constant feed of data between the client and server. I only brought up chat apps as this is a very common use for sockets. If you want the useres bell icon to update without reloading or navigating to a new page then you could look into websockets although that might be a bit overkill. You could do simple server polling as well.

Comment: Hmm never heard of server polling. Will look more into websockets and server polling. Thanks!

Comment: server polling is the old way of doing things before sockets. You basically have a timing function that just requests new notifications from your server every 5min or something like that.